# SHAP summary_plot for multilabel classification

Tags: python, plot, data-science, visualization, shap

I am trying to build a `summary_plot` using SHAP for multilabel problem, but labels overlap the plot, how can I fix that? `plt.subplots_adjust()` didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try adjusting the margins of the plot using the tight_layout()

adjust the layout of the subplots by increasing the bottom margin or decreasing the height of the subplots.

```
plt.tight_layout()


plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
```

plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2) is used to increase the bottom margin of the subplots to create more space for the labels. You can adjust the value of bottom to get the desired layout. You can also adjust other parameters of subplots_adjust such as top, left, right, and hspace to adjust the layout of the subplots.

Comment: no, didn't help

Comment: I just updated my answer. Let me know if that helps

Comment: It helped, thanks! But before shap.summary_plot I had to add fig = plt.figure()